# How to list all the employees whose name has atleast 1 A using INSTR function of SQL

Tags: sql

This question can be done using LIKE operator. I want to execute it using INSTR

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE INSTR(UPPER(COLUMN_NAME), 'A') > 0`

This works for Oracle SQL, not sure what version of SQL you are using.